# Excel VBA : How to add droplist every time i click?

Tags: vba, excel

I want when I click the drop down list button will add directly to each time I click it will be added.
this is my code

```
Sub add()
Dim myList$, i%
myList = ""
For i = 1 To 7
myList = myList & "ListItem" & i & ","
Next i
myList = Mid(myList, 1, Len(myList) - 1)
With Range("B4").Validation
.Delete
.Add _
Type:=xlValidateList, _
AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Formula1:=myList
End With

Dim Lig As Long
For Lig = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row To 6 Step -1
    If Cells(Lig, 1) = Cells(Lig - 1, 1) Then
        Rows(Lig).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Lig = Lig - 1

    End If
Next Lig
End Sub
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure on you need but there is no event, as far as I know, for the dropdown button clicked. But you could se you code in the event `Worksheet_SelectionChange`, the object `Target` will contain the new cell selected so you could change it's validation.

Hope it will help.

Comment: I just want when I click a drop-down list will add directly in excel